# Intermittent success with ADFS logins

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, adfs3.0

I'm trying to incorporate ADFS authentication in my MVC application (using [this](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/02/12/use-the-on-premises-organizational-authentication-option-adfs-with-asp-net-in-visual-studio-2013/) example). I am not the System Admin and know very little about what gets done on that side to make this happen. It works perfectly locally, but only sometimes in our staging environment. When it fails, the encoded portion of the url changes a few times and then I see

> "An error occurred. Contact your administrator for
>   more information."

The actual error in the ADFS server event log is

> "The same client browser session has made 'x' requests in the last
>   'y' seconds."

I've seen several posts talking about trailing slashes and other possible causes. I've tried those. What I'm really hoping for is a list of trouble-shooting steps to follow to find out why this happens. Our staging environment has two web servers, but the config on both is the same.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to resolve this other than debugging, either using a regular debugger or at least an http debugger.

The issue is caused by your application (the RP) or the wrong configuration.

Upon succesfull login, the rp gets the SAML token back from ADFS but for some reason instead of accepting it, the rp bounces back to ADFS.

Double check:

- what path is the RP registered under in ADFS, does the path really exists and points to an endpoint that consumes and accepts the token
- what return url your RP passes to ADFS in the `wtrealm` parameter of the signin request
- is there the `wreply` also provided by the RP and possibly points back to a wrong uri?
- what certificate is used to sign the token and is it accepted by the RP